# Loading multiple modules in JCuda is not working

Tags: cuda, jit, jcuda

In jCuda one can load cuda files as PTX or CUBIN format and call(launch) `__global__` functions (kernels) from Java.

With keeping that in mind, I want to develop a framework with JCuda that gets user's `__device__` function in a `.cu` file at run-time, loads and runs it. 
And I have already implemented a `__global__` function, in which each thread finds out the start point of its related data, perform some computation, initialization and then call user's `__device__` function.

Here is my kernel pseudo code:

```
extern "C" __device__ void userFunc(args);
extern "C" __global__ void kernel(){

    // initialize

    userFunc(args);

    // rest of the kernel
}
```

And user's `__device__` function:

```
extern "C" __device__ void userFunc(args){
    // do something
}
```

And in Java side, here is the part that I load the modules(modules are made from `ptx` files which are successfully created from cuda files with this command: `nvcc -m64 -ptx path/to/cudaFile -o cudaFile.ptx`)

```
CUmodule kernelModule = new CUmodule(); // 1 
CUmodule userFuncModule = new CUmodule(); // 2
cuModuleLoad(kernelModule, ptxKernelFileName); // 3 
cuModuleLoad(userFuncModule, ptxUserFuncFileName); // 4
```

When I try to run it I got error at line 3 : `CUDA_ERROR_NO_BINARY_FOR_GPU`. After some searching I get that my `ptx` file has some syntax error. After running this suggested command:

`ptxas -arch=sm_30 kernel.ptx`

I got:

`ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function 'userFunc'`

Even when I replace line 3 with 4 to load *userFunc* before *kernel* I get this error. I got stuck at this phase. Is this the correct way to load multiple modules that need to be linked together in JCuda? Or is it even possible?

**Edit:**

Second part of the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535828/jit-in-jcuda-loading-multiple-ptx-modules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The really short answer is: No, you can't load multiple modules into a context in the runtime API.

You can do what you want, but it requires explicit setup and execution of a JIT linking call. I have no idea how (or even whether) that has been implemented in JCUDA, but I can show you how to do it with the standard driver API. Hold on...

If you have a device function in one file, and a kernel in another, for example:

```
// test_function.cu
#include <math.h>
__device__ float mathop(float &x, float &y, float &z)
{
        float res = sin(x) + cos(y) + sqrt(z);
        return res;
}
```

and

```
// test_kernel.cu
extern __device__ float mathop(float & x, float & y, float & z);

__global__ void kernel(float *xvals, float * yvals, float * zvals, float *res)
{

        int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

        res[tid] = mathop(xvals[tid], yvals[tid], zvals[tid]);
}
```

You can compile them to PTX as usual:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -ptx test_function.cu
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -ptx test_kernel.cu
$ head -14 test_kernel.ptx
//
// Generated by NVIDIA NVVM Compiler
//
// Compiler Build ID: CL-19324607
// Cuda compilation tools, release 7.0, V7.0.27
// Based on LLVM 3.4svn
//

.version 4.2
.target sm_30
.address_size 64

        // .globl       _Z6kernelPfS_S_S_
.extern .func  (.param .b32 func_retval0) _Z6mathopRfS_S_
```

At runtime, your code must create a JIT link session, add each PTX to the linker session, then finalise the linker session. This will give you a handle to a compiled cubin image which can be loaded as a module as usual. The simplest possible driver API code to put this together looks like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda.h>

#define drvErrChk(ans) { drvAssert(ans, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

inline void drvAssert(CUresult code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != CUDA_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Driver API Error %04d at %s %d\n", int(code), file, line);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cuInit(0);

    CUdevice device;
    drvErrChk( cuDeviceGet(&device, 0) );

    CUcontext context;
    drvErrChk( cuCtxCreate(&context, 0, device) );

    CUlinkState state;
    drvErrChk( cuLinkCreate(0, 0, 0, &state) );
    drvErrChk( cuLinkAddFile(state, CU_JIT_INPUT_PTX, "test_function.ptx", 0, 0, 0) );
    drvErrChk( cuLinkAddFile(state, CU_JIT_INPUT_PTX, "test_kernel.ptx" , 0, 0, 0) );

    size_t sz;
    char * image;
    drvErrChk( cuLinkComplete(state, (void **)&image, &sz) );

    CUmodule module;
    drvErrChk( cuModuleLoadData(&module, image) );

    drvErrChk( cuLinkDestroy(state) );

    CUfunction function;
    drvErrChk( cuModuleGetFunction(&function, module, "_Z6kernelPfS_S_S_") );

    return 0;
}
```

You should be able to compile and run this as posted and verify it works OK. It should serve as a template for a JCUDA implementation, if they have JIT linking support implemented.

Comment: That was clear and complete. Thank you. I will implement its JCUDA version and post it here.

Comment: As you can see, I some how developed the JCuda version of your code. But it seems that I have some problems with passing parameters that need to be "passed by reference". Can you take a look at it?

Comment: @SonOfSun: I can't tell you why your JCUDA example doesn't work because (a) it is incomplete and (b) I know nothing about JCUDA. I have given you the precise sequence of driver API calls required to make this work and a complete example which you can compile and run for yourself and confirm it works. I don't think it is particularly good etiquette to unaccept   an answer just because you want help with what is effectively a different question from what you originally asked.

Comment: @SonOfSun: The logical thing to do is ask a new question, not change this one. If you are having problems with the JCUDA implementation, create a repro case and ask a new question. Don't change this one after it was already answered